# TortoiseGit: apply patch skips added files

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I have 2 files (one modified and a new file) as modified for a commit. I want to create a patch for this.
I created a patch using TortoiseGit and I can see that patch contains changes for both the files.

However, when I apply this patch into some repository, it applies both the changes but the new file is not shown as added. Due to this, if I simply say: git commit, the newly added file is missed out of commit.

Is this a bug of TortoiseGit or I am doing something wrong?

I tried to create a patch using 'git --diff' but in such a case, it does not include the added file as part of the patch at all.

Thanks,
Vibhav Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

Using TortoiseGit, you should create the patch by committing your changes (the modification and the addition), right clicking the repo and choosing `Create serial patch...` and choose `Number of Commits` as `1`.

Then in the other repository you right click the repo and choose `Apply serial patch...` use `Add` to add the patch file created earlier. Then click `Apply`.

This should create a new commit in the other repository containing both the modification and the new file.